# Hide password and verify password buttons from Alfresco UI New User Page and hardcode one default password for all the new users

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

My task is to hide password and verify password fields from Alfresco UI New User Page and hardcode one default password for all the new users. I have already made the custom code such that the new user is receiving the mail with username and random password...
How to hide the password and verify password fields? Any suggestion will be helpful...
[Image of the fields to be disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybqG1.png)

Comment: Refer this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653019/how-to-apply-the-css-class-hidden-to-the-field-rows-of-the-fields-needed-to-be/40673378#40673378

Answer (score 0):

Extend the user profile web-script: org/alfresco/components/profile/userprofile.get.html.ftl. Then add a class "hidden" to these inputs and set their values to your default password.